# Can you have a flexbox item not wrap, until it hits its container's width?

Tags: css, flexbox

Scenario: I want a flex item to have a flex-basis of say 500px. I want it to be able to expand as needed, with no wrapping, but only up until it hits the width of it's container. At that point, I want it to wrap. The container's width should be considered responsive and not predictable.

Semi-example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EExyLL

```
.container {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;

  .flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 16px auto;
    background: #c4f9ff;

    .item {
      flex-basis: 500px;
      max-width: 100%;
      background-color: #ffdbef;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm also open to a solution that is not based on flexbox.

Comment: What are you asking? what you want should be the default behaviour of a flex item and your fiddle shows just that

Comment: @Huangism My codepen currently wraps at the flex-basis width of 500px. That is not what I want. I want it to expand to the containers width before wrapping.

Screenshot:
https://i.imgur.com/ZrHWTAs.png

The behavior I would like is for the url text to stretch the flex item (pink background) to the full width of the container (blue background) and then wrap.

Comment: You should definitely update the wording on your question to make this more clear. Why did you set a width if you don't want a width? Do you need to set the width? Can the html change? right now you have 2 different flex containers and you are trying to align them which is not how flex works

Comment: Like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVWJqE ?

Comment: The two different containers are just showcasing part of how I want this to work. They have no relation to each other. Let me try to clarify:

I want:
- An element of some sort with a default starting width of 500px.
- I want text within it that is left-aligned.
- If the text grows larger than 500px, I want the element holding it to expand beyond 500px, to be centered, and for the text to not wrap.
- When the element containing the text expands to its container's width (say 1000px, but it could be anything), I want the text to begin wrapping.

Comment: @Huangism yes, like that, but the problem with that example is that min-width will cause the flexbox to overflow if the viewport is too small. I suppose I could use a media-query when it gets that small, but I was hoping for something fully responsive.

Comment: then use media query to update the css at 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update the items

```
.item {
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: #ffdbef;
}
```

they will start at 400 and expand to whatever the container width is and wrap. If you want it to behave differently for smaller screens then use media query to do what you need, that's how responsive design works.

I used 400 because in your pen it is 400

Updated pen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVWJqE